# How to combine whereHas() in Eloquent with optional Route parameters in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-9

What's the best way to structure `route` and `controller` in Laravel 9 for below scenario of books as part of a library filterable by type, genre, author and book UUID?

**Example paths:**

```
https://example.com/library/books/science-fiction/frank-herbert/dune-f2b69b83-8ae7-4094-9a36-b0c079764d0c
https://example.com/library/magazines/interior/dwell/edition-nov22-56d67e3c-4835-4e7b-b05a-746ebf3e0c31
```

**Routes**

Show all books from library:

```
Route::get('/library/', [BookController::class, 'bookByLibrary']);
```

Show all books from library of type:

```
Route::get('/library/{type}/', [BookController::class, 'booksByType']);
```

Show all books from library of type and genre:

```
Route::get('/library/{type}/{genre}/', [BookController::class, 'booksByGenre']);
```

Show all books from library of type, genre and author:

```
Route::get('/library/{type}/{genre}/{author}/', [BookController::class, 'booksbyAuthor']);
```

Show all detail of one specific book:

```
Route::get('/library/{type}/{genre}/{author}/{booktitle}/{uuid}', [BookController::class, 'booksByUuid']);
```

Using UUID allows to select the book avoiding having to use `library`, `type`, `genre`, `author` and `booktitle` to filter.

**I do understand the route can be written with optional parameters as follows:**

```
Route::get('/library/{type?}/{genre?}/{author?}/{booktitle?}/{uuid?}',
['BookController::class, 'getAllBooks']);
```

**But how to structure the query in controller?**

How to structure this query knowing that each parameters can be null? My attempt:

```
public function getAllBooks(Request $request, $type=null, $genre=null, $author=null, $booktitle=null, $uuid=null)
        {
        Books::query()

        ->when($request->type, fn() => $query->where('type', $type))
        ->when($request->genre, fn() => $query->where('genre', $genre))
        ->when($request->author, fn() => $query->where('author', $author))
        ->when($request->uuid, fn() => $query->where('uuid', $uuid))
        ->get();
        });
```

Does this use case lend itself installing an existing package to filter instead of building this from scratch, like Spatie's [laravel-query-builder](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-query-builder/)?